# Bind a grade to a numeric value in Prolog

Tags: error-handling, prolog

I need to use Prolog to bind a letter grade for a given integer grade value (>= 90 is a, >= 80 is b, and so on.)

evaluate_grade( X , f ) :- X >= 0.0 , X < 2.0.

This works fine:

evaluate_grade( 0.1 , G ) .

But what if someone enters a non-numeric value such as:

evaluate_grade(blahblah , G ) .

Comment: What do you expect in that case? Your original definition throws an error exception which is probably the most reasonable way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can guard your rule for accepting only ground numbers:

```
evaluate_grade( X , f ):- 
  number(X),
  X >= 0.0 , X < 2.0.
```

Test run:

```
?- evaluate_grade(0.95, X).
X = f.

?- evaluate_grade(hello, X).
false.
```

Alternatively if you want to throw an exception on bad input you may use [`must_be/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=must_be/2):

```
evaluate_grade( X , f ):-
  must_be(number, X),
  X >= 0.0 , X < 2.0.
```

test run:

```
?- evaluate_grade(0.95, X).
X = f.

?- evaluate_grade(hello, X).
ERROR: Type error: `number' expected, found `hello' (an atom)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [14] throw(error(type_error(number,hello),_24502))
ERROR:   [10] evaluate_grade(hello,f) at c:/swi/workspace/file1.pl:2174
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user: ...) at c:/swi/swi8-devel/boot/toplevel.pl:1173
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

Comment: Thanks.  But what if I want the error to simply say:  "X is not a valid number"?

Comment: In the first example I wrote you can negate the guard in another clause of the same rule. For example, using `\+(number(X))`, then print whatever and then `fail` or bind the output with your message.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this...Can you provide the rule syntax with the message?  I am playing around in the online sandbox.

Comment: for evaluate_grade(hello, X). I'd just like X = unknown_grade_value

Comment: For example, you may add a clause `evaluate_grade(X, unknown_grade_value):- \+(number(X)).`. Thats the negated guard of the first example (you wouln't use `must_be/2` in this case)

Comment: evaluate_grade( X , f ) :- must_be(number,X), X >= 0.0 , X < 2.0.
evaluate_grade(X, unknown_grade_value):- \+(number(X)).

Comment: That would't work because the first clause would throw an exception if X is not bound to a number. The first clause would use `number(X)` instead of using `must_be/2`

Comment: You are awesome.  Thanks.  Do you use Prolog somewhere in industry?